# Adding Username of person who sent DM to bot to display with their message

Tags: node.js, discord

New to JS as you can probably tell. Trying to make a discord bot that forwards its DM's to a channel on my discord.
Currently it works, sends whatever content it is sent via DM to a specific channel ID and replies "Thanks!" to the DM sender.
What code do I need to add so that it would read and send the senders "Username" and then the "Message Content" together to the DC channel?
Thank you

```
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');

// Initializing your client
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_TYPING,
        Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES,
        Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTIONS,
        Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGE_TYPING,
    ],
    partials: [
        'CHANNEL', 
    ]
});

 client.on('message', async (message) => {
    if(message.author.bot) return;
    if(message.guild) return;
    await client.channels.cache.get('DISCORD_CH_ID').send(message.content);
    console.log(message.content);
    message.author.send("Thanks")
    return;
});
client.login('TOKEN');
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're asking:

```
await client.channels.cache.get('DISCORD_CH_ID').send(`${message.author.username}: ${message.content}`);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been trying to work out how to get the two together!!
With that i've managed to get the full name with ID using:
```
 await client.channels.cache.get('965328380004302908').send(`${message.author.tag}: ${message.content}`);
```

Thank you!